# Why am I getting two different answers for this diff. equation? Completing the square vs quad form.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

With this differential equation, after seperating and integrating, and using the initial condition to solve for C, and then substituting that value of C into the general solution, I must solve for Y to get the particular solution.  Why am I getting two different solutions, where in method 1 I complete the square, and method 2, use the quadratic formula?

```
The ODE is:
```

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x}{1+2y}$

```
The initial condition is:
```

$y(2) = 0$

```
Separating and integrating, I get the general soln.:
```

$y + y^2 = x^2 + c$

```
Plugging in the initial condition:
```

$0 + 0^2 = (2)^2 + c$

$c = -4$

```
Now, plugging in (-4) into the general solution:
```

$y + y^2 = x^2 - 4$

```
Now, method 1, completing the square:
```

$y^2 + y = x^2 - 4$

$(y + \frac{1}{2})^2 = x^2 - 4 + \frac{1}{4}$

$y = -\frac{1}{2} ^+_- (4x^2 - 15)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

```
Now, method 2, quad. formula:
```

$y = \frac{-1 ^+_- (1^2 - 4(1)(-x^2+4))^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2}$

$y = -\frac{1}{2} ^+_- \frac{1}{2}(4x^2-15)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

```
So, what did I do wrong with completing the square?  
The quad. formula is the same answer from the back of the
book.  There is a 1/2 in front of the square root, whereas with 
completing the square, the 1/2 is not there.   What did I do wrong?
```

Comment: In the last line of your method 1:  $x^2 - 4 + \frac{1}{4} = x^2 - \frac{15}{4} = \frac{1}{4}(4x^2 - 15)$ and you lost that $\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left( y+ \frac{1}{2}\right)^2= x^2-\frac{15}{4} \Rightarrow y+ \frac{1}{2}= \pm \sqrt{\left( x^2-\frac{15}{4}\right) }\Rightarrow y=-\frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{\left( x^2-\frac{15}{4}\right)} \\=-\frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{ \frac{1}{4}\left( 4x^2-15\right)}= -\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\left( 4x^2-15 \right)}$$

EDIT: But since only $y(x)=-\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4x^2-15}$ satisfies the initial condition $y(2)=0$, we reject $y(x)= -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\left( 4x^2-15 \right)}$ and so our only solution is:

$$y(x)=-\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4x^2-15}$$

Comment: OH I multiplied everything within the square root by 4 to get rid of the fraction, but I shouldn't have done that, right?

Comment: If you multiply by something, you also have to divide by it.... @eestack

Comment: Yeah I'm not smart, thanks for your help!

Comment: that's a great tip I will use that

Comment: You are welcome! @eestack :)